# unable to open file using fopen(). fprintf crashing in android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, printf

I am trying to execute the below code on android.

Architecture: arm64-v8a
NDK revision: 15.2.4203891

I have also provided `write_external_storage` permissions as well.

```
FILE *pFile = fopen("/data/myfile.txt", "a");
fprintf(pFile, "HELLO WORLD!");
fflush(pFile);
fclose(pFile);
```

This is crashing with this error:

```
2-13 03:08:27.013 27451-27451/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x58 in tid 27451 (ample.hellolibs), pid 27451 (ample.hellolibs)
02-13 03:08:27.076 27485-27485/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'Android/aosp_angler/angler:8.1.0/OPM3.171019.013/tcs02091522:userdebug/test-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    ABI: 'arm64'
    pid: 27451, tid: 27451, name: ample.hellolibs  >>> com.example.hellolibs <<<
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x58
    Cause: null pointer dereference
        x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000007d249a7817  x2   0000007fffdcc440  x3   00000000000001b6
        x4   0000007fffdcc5b0  x5   0000007d3b83ea74  x6   0000007fffdcc7b0  x7   0000000070a5cbf0
        x8   0afac3eeec53c751  x9   0000007fffdcc4b0  x10  0000007fffdcc468  x11  0000007fffdcc410
02-13 03:08:27.077 27485-27485/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000007fffdcc418  x13  3a10de56bba1753f  x14  0000007dc0289000  x15  ffffffffffffffff
        x16  0000007dbf86a4b0  x17  0000007dbf7f5138  x18  0000000000000010  x19  0000000000000000
        x20  0000007fffdcc440  x21  0000007d249a7817  x22  0000007dc08c1a40  x23  0000007dbd88c290
        x24  0000000000000004  x25  0000007dc08c1a40  x26  0000007d3bcbeaa0  x27  0000000000000001
        x28  0000007fffdcc510  x29  0000007fffdcc370  x30  0000007dbf8163c0
        sp   0000007fffdcc320  pc   0000007dbf7f5164  pstate 0000000060000000
02-13 03:08:27.195 27485-27485/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
        #00 pc 0000000000056164  /system/lib64/libc.so (vfprintf+44)
        #01 pc 00000000000773bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (fprintf+112)
02-13 03:08:27.196 27485-27485/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000000077c  /data/app/com.example.hellolibs-5RHGoggEKPs6kq-HxHOb1w==/lib/arm64/libhello-libs.so (Java_com_example_hellolibs_MainActivity_stringFromJNI+64)
        #03 pc 0000000000553bf0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144)
        #04 pc 000000000054ab88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
        #05 pc 00000000000dc594  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+204)
        #06 pc 000000000029b49c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
        #07 pc 0000000000295a90  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+700)
        #08 pc 0000000000532ad8  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+652)
        #09 pc 000000000053c914  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
```

ndk-stack gives the below output:

```
s/app/build/intermediates/cmake/arm8/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/libhello-libs.so
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/c7proltedd/c7prolte:7.0/NRD90M/C701FDDU1BRC2:user/release-keys'
pid: 23318, tid: 23318, name: tify.newjnilibc  >>> com.lenovo.notify.newjnilibc <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Stack frame #00 pc 000000000006c5b4  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
Stack frame #01 pc 0000000000069a38  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+64)
Stack frame #02 pc 0000000000024a00  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+24)
Stack frame #03 pc 000000000001cdac  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+52)
Stack frame #04 pc 000000000042ed2c  /system/lib64/libart.so
```

Comment: what does `ndk-stack` say?

Comment: Please show us your code as well.

Comment: Also note that you will need `write_external_storage` permissions in order to write to external storage

Comment: @DmitriiZ. In which folder do we have permission to write?

Comment: You can write to your apps directory without additional permitions. See [getFilesDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()), you can either pass it from java or use JNI to get this in your c++ code

Comment: Is `pFile` null?

Answer (score 1):

ndk-stack -sym ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/ -dump

You can use above command to get ndk stack